# Reactjs: change component dynamically after ajax

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my code:

```
export default class Index extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        
        this.state = {
            myCom: 'Header'
        }
    }

    componentWillMount(){
        fetch('api...').then(response => response.json()).then(jsonData => {
            this.setState({
                myCom: jsonData.value
            })
        }).catch(error => {
            //
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <{this.state.myCom} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

By default I want load `Header` component

After Ajax, I want change it dynamically

I don't want use `if/else` or `swtich`

Because my components are lot

Comment: Call the API in didmount and didUpdate. Dont block your render. Also please include your code where you will be rerendering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all please avoid using async calls in `componentWillMount()`, this can cause infinite rerendering, [Read More about this issue](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount). now coming to your question, its highly unlikely  react supports dynamic routing is this format. this code will probably not compile. your best bet is to get a component name via a AJAX call and render the component using a renderControll function. in your current implementation u are not defining/importing any components and their definition so dynamic impoting doesn't work this way.

you will have to follow something like this

```js
import Component1 from "componentes/c1" 
import Component2 from "componentes/c1" 
import Component3 from "componentes/c1" 
import Component4 from "componentes/c1" 

const componentRenderer (componentName)=>{
  switch(componentName){
    case 'c1' : return <Component1/>
        case 'c2' : return <Component2/>
            case 'c3' : return <Component3/>
                case 'c4' : return <Component4/>
   
  }
}
export default class Index extends React.Component {
   
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        
        this.state = {
            myCom: 'Header'
        }
    }

    componentdidMount(){
        fetch('api...').then(response => response.json()).then(jsonData => {
            this.setState({
                myCom: jsonData.value
            })
        }).catch(error => {
            //
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {componentRenderer(this.state.myCom)}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```